# AppMaker: I got a TypeError while adding a variable link in a TableRow

Tags: google-app-maker

And I have something like in a `onClick`:

```
alert ("Formulario: "+widget.datasource.item.TipoTareas.Formulario);
app.showPage("app.pages."+widget.datasource.item.TipoTareas.Formulario);
```

The first sentence gives me the correct answer. But the second gives me an error:

> TypeError: VCan not read $d property of undefined

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var form=widget.datasource.item.TipoTareas.Formulario;
var allPages = app.pages._values;

for (var i = 0; i < allPages.length; i++) {
    if (form == allPages[i].displayName) {
        app.showPage(allPages[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to this as well:

```
var pagename = widget.datasource.item.TipoTareas.Formulario;
var pages = app.pages._values;
var index = pages.map(function(i) {return i.displayName;}).indexOf(pagename);

if (index !== -1) {
  app.showPage(pages[index]);
}
```

However I would advise against using the page displayName in your scenario as this value does not have to be unique, vs just the page name is unique and AM will not allow duplication of page names.